# Don't allow touch events on items below view

Tags: android, listview, bottom-sheet

I have a ListView with video items. When user clicks the image of the Video it goes to a new screen and starts playing the video. If user clicks a button next to the video image then I display a `BottomSheet` from google design library. Because I want to apply a shadow when `bottomSheet` is expanded I have a View with a transparent dark overlay just above the ListView, which initially has visibility set to Gone and I change it to Visible when I expand `BottomSheet`.

The problem is that despite the shadow layer items below it can still get click events which is a behavior I want to prevent. Is there a solution for this ? Maybe an attribute for that view so when its visible won't let touch events happen ?

Answer (score 1):

Hey if you want to disable the  touch intercept capability of view by you self. If it is a button or Views like Linearlayout, RelativeLayout  just use `view.setClickable(false)` once you hide the view. Otherwise views intecept touch events even ,if they are not visible(Given that none other views are intercepting touch event for that portion of screen).